# In scripted pipeline, how to get Jenkins build parameters

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a set of remote nodes in my system, and each node has a set of defined labels.  I need a Jenkins script that can print out the parameters of the Build running on all remote nodes that have a matching label.

I can get the Executor object on the remote node, but I don't know how to get access to the parameters of the Build that is currently running on that remote node.

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

def GetRemoteBuildParameters(host){

    // find all remote nodes with matching label(s)
    def label = Jenkins.instance.getLabel(host)
    def nodes = label.getNodes()

    // our label should match with >= 1 node, but check to be sure
    assert nodes.size() > 0

    // TODO: print all parameters of build that is running on each node
    nodes.each{ node ->

        // only care about online nodes
        if (node.toComputer().isOnline()){

            // a node may have > 1 Executor
            node.toComputer().getExecutors().each{ e ->

                // at this point, 'e' is an Executor
                // but I don't know how to access the 'Build' running on 'e'
                println e.getDisplayName()
                println e.getCurrentExecutable()

                // I think the following line gets me access to a Job,
                // not a Build
                println e.getCurrentExecutable().getParent()
            }
        }
    }
}
GetRemoteBuildParameters("foo")
```

In my example above, if nodes A and B both had label 'foo', I want to print out all parameters of the Builds on both A and B.  *Note that for now I am assuming that A and B are both running a Build; I will deal with that condition later.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shows the best answer that I have found to date: https://github.com/cloudbees/jenkins-scripts/blob/master/get-build-information.groovy#L24

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variable BUILD_NUMBER. To print current build number you can use like this

```
echo "${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
```

Comment: I think that can only be used within a script that is currently running on the remote slave.  I'm looking to run a script on the master, which queries the remote slave to see the parameters of a job running on the slave.  Therefore, BUILD_NUMBER would give me the number of the job running on the master, not the slave.